# Does reducing the clear juice from tomatoes have a name?

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

I have been cooking a very light tomato topping for tortellini using dicing tomatoes.  I saute them *very* briefly until the flesh begins to soften, then remove the pieces from the pan leaving whatever juice cooked out of the tomatoes there.  This liquid is then reduced until it is a syrup, and recombined with the pieces.

Does this technique have a name?  Is it weird?

Comment: Something akin to [tomato water](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/06/how-to-make-tomato-water.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already given the name for this process in your question. Reduction is the cooking term used for thickening and intensifying the flavor of a food by simmering or boiling away some of the liquid.

Comment: Would I call this dish sauteed tomatoes in reduced tomato water?

Answer (score 3):

A'jus is the culinary name for natural juice and sounds much better than water. So, tomatoes in tomato a'jus reduction would be correct. Personally I would leave off the term reduction though(too lengthily)

Comment: Do you mean [au jus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_jus)? It's French for "with juice", so while that juice is often reduced and/or thickened into a sauce or gravy, the correct usage is more like "beef au jus" or "served au jus". American English has turned it into a noun, so you'll sometimes also see "sandwich with au jus sauce" - sounds awful to me, but language is ugly so there you are. But "tomato au jus reduction" is an even further reach, not something I've really seen. "Tomatoes au jus" makes sense, though, I suppose.